# Detecting the end of a html form's tabindex to fire a jQuery event

Tags: jquery, html, tabindex

I have a html table with form elements in each row to add items, prices, quantities etc... to an invoice.

At the end of each table row there is an 'add' button which fires an event to add an new row of blank form elements to the bottom of the table (for a new item on the invoice).

Is there a way to detect that the last form element in the table has lost focus (tabbed passed it) and fire the event to add a new row of empty elements?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: add onblur event on those "add" buttons?

Comment: I would be very interested to know why everyone is suggesting blur as opposed to focus. Is there any reason for this? - Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Blur's what you want](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). Something like this:

```
$('.add-button').blur(function() {
     add_row();
});
```

Comment: this did the trick in the end - thanks for the tip!  `$('a.add_item').focus(function(){$(this).trigger('click')});`

Answer (score 0):

Attach a blur event to the last row, last cell.

```
$('table tr:last-child td:last-child').blur(function() {
     // add row function
});
```

Read: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get rid of the add button? If so, you should add a class to the last element of each new row (ie. 'last') and use blur

```
$('.last').blur(function() { 
    //code to add new row of elements
});
```